# Python: how to set value to a list element

Tags: python

I have a list, say named `mac`, which saves 6-bytes mac address. I want to set the last byte to 0, then I use:

```
mac[5] = 0
```

But it gives me error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 7):

because `mac` is a `str` and strings are immutable in python.

```
mac = list(mac)
mac[5] = '0'
mac = ''.join(mac) #to get mac in str
```

or use `bytearray`, which could function as a mutable string.

```
>>> x = bytearray('abcdef')
>>> x
bytearray(b'abcdef')
>>> x[5] = '0'
>>> x
bytearray(b'abcde0')
>>> str(x)
'abcde0'
```

Comment: Dose this way add a character '0' or just 0?

Comment: @EvanLi it sets character at index 5 (or the 6th character) to `'0'`.

Comment: Don't forget `''.join((mac[:5],'0',mac[6:]))`

Comment: After test, <code>mac = mac[:5] + '\x00'</code> is what I need. Thank you anyway.